# connecting to hadoop database tables

Tags: python, database, hadoop, ssh

Currently we are pulling database tables from Hadoop server through AMBARI or PUTTY connections. But I would like to know is there any efficient way to pull database tables through python jupyter directly without using AMBARI or PUTTY.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by Hadoop database because neither Hive nor Hadoop are databases.

Yes, Jupyter works fine. So do libraries like pyhive

If you specifically want to use sql only, look at HUE or Apache Superset.

Of course, JDBC/ODBC clients like DBVisualizer and Tableau work too